# Value not getting updated in recursive function Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, recursion

I need to get file details of all files inside a folder(ad its subfolders). I have written a recursive function for this purpose.

```
private async Task getallfiles(StorageFolder appfolder)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> sortedItems1 = await appfolder.GetFilesAsync();
        if (sortedItems1.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (StorageFile file in sortedItems1)
                CopyContentToIsolatedStorage(file.Path);
        }

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> sorteditems2 = await appfolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        if (sorteditems2.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (StorageFolder folder in sorteditems2)
                await getallfiles(folder); 
        }
    }
```

Now when I am calling this function with the root folder passed as parameter, I am getting only the files in the root folder inside sorteditems, which is a global variable. I tried passing different folders as parameters but everytime the sorteditems that was returned contained only the files in the parent folder passes and none of the files in the sub-folders.

Am I missing something or is there something logically wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated.

The exception I am getting - it might help in finding the issue:

{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Appzillon.MainPage.d__3d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Appzillon.MainPage.d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__0(Object state)}.

Also the function CopyContentToIsolatedStorage is as follows:

```
public static void CopyContentToIsolatedStorage(string file)
    {
        // Obtain the virtual store for the application.
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (iso.FileExists(file))
            return;

        var fullDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        if (!iso.DirectoryExists(fullDirectory))
            iso.CreateDirectory(fullDirectory);

        // Create a stream for the file in the installation folder.
        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            // Create a stream for the new file in isolated storage.
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile(file))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the file from the installation folder to isolated storage. 
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Updated code and added the exception I am getting. The reason I was getting only root folder files was because I had taken sortedItems as Readonly as kennyzx has mentioned. But even after trying his modified code and in fact also changing it to the above updated code, I am getting issues. Please see my comments to kennyzx's answer...

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have declared `sortedItems` as `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>`, so `sortedItems` can not be modified (that is why it's called **ReadOnlyList**); In your code, the `Concat` method generates a **new list** combining `sortedItems` and `sortedItems1`, the files are not actually added to `sortedItems`.

So first declare `sortedItems` as `List<StorageFile>`, which supports adding another list to **itself**.

and you forget the `await` keyword before calling the method recursively.

```
List<StorageFile> sortedItems = new List<StorageFile>();

private async Task getallfiles(StorageFolder appfolder)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> sortedItems1 = await appfolder.GetFilesAsync();           
        sortedItems.AddRange(sortedItems1);

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> sorteditems2 = await appfolder.GetFoldersAsync();
    if (sorteditems2.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (StorageFolder folder in sorteditems2)
            await getallfiles(folder); //add await
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just before I saw your answer I had somewhere read about about async tasks and changed my function to an async task and also added the await. But yes as you guesses rightly, my declaration of sortedItems was wrong. But despite those changes, the code is still breaking in between. As my actual motive is to copy the files to isolated storage, I have written a function CopyContentToIsolatedStorage(StorageFolder folder) for that. I decided to replace the AddRange(previously concat) statement with the above function using a foreach function on the sortedItems1 List. contd...

Comment: The new replaced code is as below:                            `if (sortedItems1.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (StorageFile file in sortedItems1)
                    CopyContentToIsolatedStorage(file.Path);
            }`                                                    instead of    `sortedItems.AddRange(sortedItems1);`               Even after this the code was breaking with the same error. But one thing I seem to have understood is that its an async issue only as after app crash, when I am checking the isolated storage of the app, the files copied and the ...contd...

Comment: you can edit your own question with the new code, and post the implementation of `CopyContentToIsolatedStorage`.

Comment: number of files copied is different every time. Thus it is probably because of sync async issues only. But as I am not very versed with async programming, I am unable to move further.... Also I am getting the same exception every time. Just mentioning it as it might be of help in finding the issue...contd...

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments. Have updated the code in my question and also provided the exception I am getting... Thanks for the help... Hoping to get this issue resolved....

Comment: Sorry my bad. Your code seems to work fine. The code was breaking because of empty files in the folder which I was trying to copy.